# IvoryGoogleMapBundle - map doesn't show

Tags: php, google-maps, symfony, google-maps-api-3

I have problem with IvoryGoogleMapBundle. I've installed it (add lines in composer.json and AppKernel.php, also added configuration in config.yml but removed class and helper_class parameters) but when I'm using

```
        {{ google_map_js(map) }}
    {{ google_map_css(map) }}
    {{ google_map_container(map) }}
```

in twig, only black rectangle shape appears.

In page source this appears:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
map_5346b73f6f0f3024962917_container = {"map":null,"coordinates":{},"bounds":{},"points":{},"sizes":{},"circles":{},"encoded_polylines":{},"ground_overlays":{},"polygons":{},"polylines":{},"rectangles":{},"info_windows":{},"marker_images":{},"marker_shapes":{},"markers":{},"marker_cluster":null,"kml_layers":{},"event_manager":{"dom_events":{},"dom_events_once":{},"events":{},"events_once":{}},"closable_info_windows":{},"functions":{"to_array":function (object) { var array = []; for (var key in object) { array.push(object[key]); } return array; }}};
map_5346b73f6f0f3024962917_container.coordinates.coordinate_5346b73f6eb8d631196403 = coordinate_5346b73f6eb8d631196403 = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0, true);
map_5346b73f6f0f3024962917_container.map = map_5346b73f6f0f3024962917 = new google.maps.MapView(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {"mapTypeId":google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,"zoom":3,"disableDefaultUI":true,"disableDoubleClickZoom":true});
map_5346b73f6f0f3024962917.setCenter(coordinate_5346b73f6eb8d631196403);
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#map_canvas{
width:300px;
height:300px;
border:1px solid #000;
background_color:#fff;
}
</style>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:300px;height:300px;"></div>
```

Does IvoryGoogleMapBundle need any google maps api key or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You must render the html before the js, try:

```
{{ google_map_container(map) }}
{{ google_map_css(map) }}
{{ google_map_js(map) }}
```

To your second question, yes, you need to include the APIv3 from Google, and provide a Server API Key.

Comment: I still have problem with mapy. Here http://pastebin.com/dZ5R9vwJ  is what I've got when i render only  simple twig template: http://pastebin.com/Kusd8js5

Still map won't render :/

I used google hello word example and it worked like a charm. Please help me :(